# Only partial background color on element that's wider than the window width when scrolling

Tags: css, html

I have some sections which have a background color applied. When the browser window width is less than the width of the page the horizontal scroll appears but the area of the element with the background color reduces also - the color only applies to a portion of the elements equal to the window width starting from the left.

I've reduced the HTML and CSS to the minimum that still displays the issue. I've viewed this on IE11 and FF42.0.

```css
h3 {font-size: 3em;}
.widthContainer {width: 960px;}
.test {background-color: #3870d0;}
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <div class="widthContainer">
        <h3>The background color won't cover the whole heading!</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `max-width` worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `div` elements have a width of `100%` of their parent element's width. In this case, your `.test` element with the background has the same width as the window, which is why the background doesn't cover beyond the width of the window.

The only way to work around this is to set an explicit `width`/`min-width` on the element with the background or on one of its ancestor elements.

```css
h3 {font-size: 3em;}
.container { min-width: inherit; /* optional */}
.test {background-color: #3870d0; min-width: 960px; }
```

```html
<div class="test">
    <div class="container">
        <h3>The background color will cover the whole heading!</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks - I added min-width to the body element

Answer (score 0):

If you use `max-width` it will do what you want.

Comment: I will be making it more fluid in future but for now I'm happy with the fixed width. I just want that background colour behind the full width of that element even when the element is wider than the window

Comment: Actually, the inelegant way to do this, would be adding a windowResized event and update all the objects on the screen.